# drag and drop columns doesn't work in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html-table

I created some functions in js to make the columns of the table change order by drag and drop , in simple webapp with html,css and js , everything works fine , but with the same functions and the same table it doesn't work in reactjs  . I don't know why .

here is the functions :

```
  const table = document.getElementById('Mytable');
        let dragData = {};

        // Add dragstart event listeners to all draggable <th> elements
        const draggableHeaders = document.querySelectorAll('th[draggable="true"]');
        draggableHeaders.forEach(header => {
            header.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart);
            header.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver);
            header.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
            header.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave);
            header.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
            header.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd);
        });

        function handleDragStart(event) {
            const columnIndex = Array.from(event.target.parentNode.children).indexOf(event.target);
            dragData = { column: columnIndex };
            event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', event.target.outerHTML);
            event.target.classList.add('dragging');
        }

        function handleDragOver(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        function handleDragEnter(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        function handleDragLeave(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        function handleDrop(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const targetColumnIndex = Array.from(event.target.parentNode.children).indexOf(event.target);

            // Swap columns by reordering <th> elements
            const headerRow = table.querySelector('thead tr');
            const headerCells = Array.from(headerRow.children);
            const tempCell = headerCells[dragData.column].cloneNode(true);
            headerCells[dragData.column].innerHTML = headerCells[targetColumnIndex].innerHTML;
            headerCells[targetColumnIndex].innerHTML = tempCell.innerHTML;

            // Swap columns by reordering <td> elements
            const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
            rows.forEach(row => {
                const cells = Array.from(row.children);
                const tempContent = cells[dragData.column].innerHTML;
                cells[dragData.column].innerHTML = cells[targetColumnIndex].innerHTML;
                cells[targetColumnIndex].innerHTML = tempContent;
            });

            // Reset the dragging state
            event.target.classList.remove('dragging');
        }

        function handleDragEnd(event) {
            event.target.classList.remove('dragging');
        }
```

this the table (just thead ) :

```
<thead className="bordered-row">
      <tr className="bordered-row">
        <th  data-column="1" draggable="true">ID</th>
        <th  data-column="2" draggable="true">Nom</th>
        <th  data-column="3" draggable="true">Adresse</th>
        <th  data-column="4" draggable="true">Type</th>
        <th  data-column="5" draggable="true">Categorie</th>
        <th  data-column="6" draggable="true">GPS</th>
        <th  data-column="7" draggable="true">Progression</th>
        <th  data-column="8" draggable="true" className='plus-container'><button className='plus'><img src={plus}></img></button> </th>
        <th  data-column="9" draggable="true" class="departure-arrival">Départ</th>
        <th  data-column="10" draggable="true" class="departure-arrival">Arrivée</th>
        <th  data-column="11" draggable="true" >Attribut</th>
        <th  data-column="12" draggable="true" className='feed'> Feed </th>
        
      </tr>
    </thead>
```